# Excel Formula - IF Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I hope this will be easy. I am working on an over-time spreadsheet that lists people's overtime hours. For every 12 hours worked they will receive 1 award point. I'd like it so when the sum of the OT hours box hits 12,24,48 etc it adds 1.0 to the award points cell. This is what I have so far:

```
=IF(B28=12,"1.0",0)
```

I essentially want this to add another 1.0 point for every additional 12 hours worked. So, at 24 it will add another 1.0 point.

Comment: Please edit your question title, ALL CAPS is considered SHOUTING AT US.

Comment: why not just divide B28 by 12? that will give you the multiplying fatcor. And don't put "1.0" as you enter a number as text.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use IF. You can just divide and round down:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(B28/12;0)
```